Trackpad not working on MacBook Air 2020 but the keyboard is working fine
I am new to Ubuntu and installed it yesterday. I am facing a issue with the built in trackpad in my MacBook Air. It is not working but the keyboard is working fine after installing some drivers and dependencies.
To view it I installed hwinfo and this came as the result of hwinfo --short

After reading this is came to know that no input event has been assigned to the Apple internal keyboard/trackpad in the mouse section, but it's assigned in the keyboard section. Can someone explain how I can activate the built-in trackpad of the MacBook?
This is the output of lsb_release -a
2

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.

I have attached the image of lsb_release -a
